# WP Core Update will leave wp-content alone?

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

Hi I have a wordpress website and want to update via wp-cli.

Will the command `wp core update` leave the wp-content folder alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[user@server]$ wp core update* will not update the wp-content folder ideally.

You should be careful with WP CLI as it can upgrade to a major version of wordpress instead of a minor one. This might lead to plugin incompatibility.

Please use the following commands to check the version and upgrade to a minor version if necessary.

*[user@server]$ wp core version*

*[user@server]$ wp core update --minor*

Also it is a very good idea to take a complete backup before updating your wordpress installation.

You can use a free plugin like Duplicator which will give you a nice backup for your installation.

Happy updating!!

Answer (score 4):

The upgrade process will affect all files and folders included in the main WordPress installation(Mainly it's wp-admin and wp-includes). This includes all the core files used to run WordPress. If you have made any modifications to those files, your changes will be lost.

Simply, you can change only wp-content files. And **wp-content will not be affected by core update**.

**But, I suggest to take backup before any update.**